# Alternative design pattern to a base class function call

Tags: c++

I have a base class that clients can "shut down":

```
struct base {
  void shutdown() {
    //code
  }
};
```

But clients can (if they want) create a subclass to suit their own needs:

```
struct der : public base {
  void shutdown(double some, int other, bool parameters) {
    //custom shutdown stuff
    base::shutdown(); //<- thus MUST be called
  }
};
```

The problem is that the client must **remember** to call `base::shutdown()` (the superclass creator will document this to subclass developers). This seems error-prone, as **nothing is enforced at compile-time**.

Are there alternative design patterns to solve this in some way?

Comment: use the class's destructor to perform the "shutdown".

Comment: @DavidBrown It's not a shut down in that sense, because the objects should be usable (and will be used) after they are "shut down".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is one of those cases where you "have to do the right thing" when writing the code. This applies to many things in programming. If you don't do the right calculations when calculating something, that's also wrong. Or if you call a function twice that should only be called once. Or not calling it at all when it has to be called. All of these things are "doing it wrong". You can't prevent programmers from making mistakes...

Of course, if you hadn't added a bunch of extra parameters, you could do it "in reverse" by having a non-virtual function in the base-class that doesn't get overridden, and then let the base-class call a `virtual` function in the derived class. As I said, it doesn't work if you have parameters that aren't present in the base class that needs to go into the derived class.

An example of what I mean:

```
struct base {
  void shutdown() final {   // final: it can't be overridden in derived class
    do_shutdown();   // Calls derived function's 
    // ... more code here ... 
  }
  virtual void do_shutdown() { }    // default is "do nothing". 
};


struct der: public base
{
   // not overriding `shutdown`, but overriding `do_shutdown`
   void do_shutdown()
   {
      .. some code goes here .. 
   }
}
```

Now the call to `der->shutdown()` will call the base-class's implementation, which calls `do_shutdown` in the derived class before completing the in the base-class's `shutdown`.

However, like I said, you can't add extra parameters when you do this - in fact, deriving a class and changing the parameters is "wrong" - not so wrong you can't possibly ever do it, but it tends to be a bad thing when using inheritance polymorphism, because the whole purpose of polymorphism is that there is some common code that "doesn't know if it's a base class object, a derived1 object or a derived2 object" - so if it needs to know which kind of object to pass the correct number of arguments, it gets a bit meaningless.

Comment: You should make `shutdown() final` or subclasses could still override it directly.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry about it. It's similar to the assignment operator of derived classes. It's not your fault if the subclass developer forgets to call it, but it's not an error if it isn't either.

[C++ FAQ entry on the subject](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-op-in-derived-class.html)